# Gulp watch absolute path

Tags: gulp, assets, gulp-watch, taskmanager

trying to get this work:

```
gulp.task('default', undefined, function(){
    gulp.watch('/Volumes/jobs/slim/SLIM Websites/boilerplate.weareslim.de/layout/_assets/**/*.{png,jpg,svg,psd,ai}', ['syncAssets']);
});
```

in my "_assets" folder under "layout" I have multiple sub directories like "png","jpg","svg", etc. I want gulp to look all of these through to notice a change than fire my "syncAssets" task.

But somehow its not working and i think it has something to do with the way I selected the sub directories?